# How can I get a div to change its background-image after a specific event has taken place?

Tags: javascript

I have made a game using JavaScript and I would like the background to change after the game is over or after isGamerOver = true to be more specific. Here is what I currently have. Right now when ever the game ends I get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.

```
function gameOver() {
    console.log('game over')
    isGamerOver = true
    while (grid.firstChild) {
        grid.removeChild(grid.firstChild)
    }
    grid.innerHTML = score
   
    clearInterval(upTimerId)
    clearInterval(downTimerId)
    clearInterval(leftTimerId)
    clearInterval(rightTimerId)
   
    if(isGamerOver = true){
    document.getElementById("grid").style.backgroundImage="url('backgrounds/background-up.png')";
    }else{
    document.getElementById("grid").style.backgroundImage="url('backgrounds/game-over.png')";
    }
}
```

Here is the style sheet I am trying to change

```
.grid  {
width: 400px;
height: 600px;
background-image: url(backgrounds/background-up.png);  
position: relative;
font-size: 100px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
}
```

Here Is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"  dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>100% Not Doodle Jump</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link>
        <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="grid"></div>
    
    </body>
 </html>
```

I also added a div in JavaScript

```
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
const doodler = document.createElement('div')
```

Comment: share some html , you could be missing the id

Comment: You're using `getElementById` but your CSS has `.grid`, indicating that "grid" is a *class*, not an *id*

Comment: Okay I updated the code to include my HTML elements as well. I changed the getElementById to getElementsByClassName and I still get the same Uncaught TypeError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got your grid defined like that:

```
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
```

change this:

```
if(isGamerOver = true){
   document.getElementById("grid").style.backgroundImage="url('backgrounds/background-up.png')";
}else{
   document.getElementById("grid").style.backgroundImage="url('backgrounds/game-over.png')";
}
```

to this:

```
if(isGamerOver = true){
   grid.style.backgroundImage="url('backgrounds/background-up.png')";
}else{
   grid.style.backgroundImage="url('backgrounds/game-over.png')";
}
```